# CGAL with tensorflow example

Tags: c++, tensorflow, header

I tried to compile tensorflow 1.13.1 into a C++-useable form for CGAL, but I always fail during linkage, because some core-classes are missing in the built tensorflow shared library, e.g. "tensorflow::Tensor::Tensor()" is missing.
Somebody has a recipe for this issues ? The tensorflow C-API headers is not complete at all for usage within CGAL.

Comment: The C API is completely different from the C++ one. There is currently no official binary distribution of the C++ library and API headers. See the [Installation notes of CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title37) for instructions about how you can build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but CGAL itself is not the issue, I have a complete cmake-compilation of CGAL with demos,examples without compilation or linking problems. The only problem is the integration of the C++-based tensorflow for the mentioned classification example. I am still wondering how INRA could succeed...